# EXE file created from py not running

Tags: python, selenium, exe, cx-freeze

I have a file in Python 3.4 which I have converted in *exe* using *cx_freeze*. When I double click the file I get nothing, seems its opening, and closing on its own however when I go to the command prompt n run it I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Mytime.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 43, in _init_
    self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 64, in _init_
    WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34\\build\\exe.win32-3.4\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

What's missing?

Comment: It looks like you hardcoded the path to a file that isn't there wherever you're running this from, but I can't tell because you didn't post any code.

Comment: Note that using the Windows file explorer to directly run most simple programs that terminate causes the window to close before you can see the output. In general, use the command prompt/terminal to be able to see the full printout.

Comment: @Natecat  m calling                                                                               from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

Comment: Is selenium installed? is firefox installed?

Comment: @Natecat yes it is, infact i have ran the code thru eclipse ide(thats where i write all my scripts) and then wanna convert it to exe.

Comment: It looks like selenium doesn't expect to be loaded from a zip file (which is what the frozen application does). The only fix I know of is to modify it to look for that file elsewhere. http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files